# How can I protect a disabled form from being submitted?

Tags: forms

I need to protect **URL alias** from being submitted.
[image]

I've tried setting #disabled, #access, unset(), and what not. It hides the form, but the user is still able to modify the form on the client-side and submit it.

How do I prevent this form from being submitted on the client-side?

My current module code

```
<?php
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state){
  if (empty($form['type']['#value'])) return;
  $form['#after_build'][] = 'mymodule_after_built';
}

function mymodule_after_built($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['path']['#access'] = FALSE;
  $form['path']['alias']['#access'] = FALSE;
  $form['path']['alias']['#value'] = $form['path']['alias']['#default_value'];

  return ($form);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

To clear the question, I am not asking how to hide the form, but how to prevent the end-user from manually altering the code and submitting the form I just hid.

End-user can just edit source code and add `<input type="text" id="edit-path-alias" name="path[alias]" value="" size="60" maxlength="255" class="form-text">` and still enter the alias.

Comment: Why don't you just unset this field in `hook_form_alter` directly? I mean, a whole vertical tab. Try. And if you try and fail, post the code you tried. Make sure you inspect form's structure first, with `kpr`, `var_dump` or something.

Comment: I've tried `unset($form['path'])` in `hook_form_alter`. As far as I know, it's not possible to unset the form in `hook_form_alter`, unless attaching it to `#after_built`.

Comment: I never experienced any serious problems with unsetting form elements directly. So 1) how do you know it's really `$form['path']`? 2) What exactly happened when you tried?

Comment: Also, see https://www.drupal.org/node/1131786 - was this what you are using? If solution stopped working, consider reopening that issue...

Comment: Good article. Yeah, because path is added in `path_form_alter`, it's not accessible in `hook_form_alter`, which is why `#after_built` seems like it's the only way to override it.

Comment: ...so the solution works. My question is that although I am able to hide the element, the end-user is still able to manually edit html code to send the form, even-though it's not present.

Comment: I've updated the question for clarity

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue! It seems to be a Drupal bug.

`#access` set in `#after_build` does not completely override the `#access` settings, set in `hook_form_alter`.

In theory, a form is altered by `hook_form_alter` and `hook_form_alter` is altered by `#after-build`. When I try setting `#access` in `hook_form_alter`, to alter the form, everything works. However, when I try setting `#access` permissions in `#after_build`, to alter `hook_form_alter`, it only hides the form, still allowing anyone to submit it, by altering the code on the client side.

As a temporary solution, I disabled URL alias permissions, by unchecking "Administer URL aliases" and "Create and edit URL aliases".

Answer (score 0):

If you set #access to FALSE in #after_build callback, the value will not be submitted even if it's sent to server.

Comment: That's what I thought also. But it is actually submitted to the server. My code example already sets the element `#access` to `FALSE`, but I'm still able to manually send the form to the server.

Comment: Send is okay. But form API should not pass it in $form_state['values'] in submit callback. Does it?